# RSyntaxTextArea and Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

How to add RSyntaxTextArea to JPanel in Netbeabs?
I tried this way, but it does not work in the init, I always gets a gray jPanel nothing happens.

```
RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_PYTHON);
RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
jPanel2.add(sp);
```

Thank you

Comment: does it work when you add jtextArea ?what is the layout of panel

Comment: Try changing the layout manager for the `JPanel` to `BorderLayout`

Comment: @MadProgrammer changing the layout manager to BorderLayout works 100%, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JPanel` honours the `preferredSize` of the components been added to it.  `JScrollPane` will also honour the `preferredSize` of the view (or at least the `JViewport` will).  If the component does not use the `Scrollabe` interface, the `JScrollPane` will use the component's/view's `preferredSize` to make determinations about how big it should be.  If the `preferredSize` of the component is `0x0`, then components will appear "invisible".

Try using a different layout manager for the `JPanel`, something like `BorderLayout` for example

As per [the example](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea), you may also want to provide sizing hints via the constructor...

```
RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(20, 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you haven't add **jPanel2** to the layout yet , i guess your code is working fine  , ] just add the **jPanel2** to the layout 
 add this method to your code !

```
this.add(jPanel2);
```

hope it helps

Comment: I added the jPanel2 to the layout using drag and drop in the netbeans design GUI. it still does not work.

Comment: have you added this method

'textArea.setFoldIndicatorEnabled(true);'